# Symbian, Java ME: determine if phone has touch screen

Tags: java-me, symbian, touchscreen

is there a way to know from code if phone has touch screen or not?

I need it for smth like `if (PhoneHasTouchScreen) enable_something()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps call [`Canvas.hasPointerMotionEvents()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#hasPointerMotionEvents%28%29).  Bear in mind that there are two types of touch screen in Java ME; a touch screen that uses the usual style pointer/softkey events, and the style that returns pointer co-ordinates when you touch the screen.  For all usefulness on your app, consider the former to not be touch screen at all.

Comment: Thanks, basically I want to add support for left/light option hardware keys for device without any kind of touch screen and hide it if phone has touch screen. I got some problem with getting access to these from GameCanvas.